# Compiler Error in Function Template with VS2010 SP1

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2010, compiler-bug

Why i get the marked compiler error (C2899)? I tried with VS2010 SP1.

```
#include <list>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

template <typename source_container_type, typename target_container_type>
void copy_all(const source_container_type& source, target_container_type& target)
 {
    std::for_each(begin(source), end(source), [&] (const typename source_container_type::value_type& element)
    {
        // error C2899: typename cannot be used outside a template declaration
        // error C2653: 'target_container_type' : is not a class or namespace name
         target.push_back(typename target_container_type::value_type(element));
    });
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> a;
    a.push_back(23);
    a.push_back(24);
    a.push_back(25);

    std::list<int> b;
    copy_all(a, b);
}
```

Kind regards
Simon

PS: I know i could use `std::copy(..)` with `std::back_inserter(..)` - but that's not the point.

**EDIT**

The question was answered in a comment by perreal:
http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/694857/bug-in-lambda-expressions

**EDIT**

Please note that i'm not interested in workarounds. I want to know whether the code above should compile or not.

Comment: This looks like a bug: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/694857/bug-in-lambda-expressions. Your code works in g++ 4.6.2

Comment: The lambda has some role in here, because without it, it works.

Comment: Typedef'ing the problematic type helps. `typedef typename target_container_type::value_type target_vt; [...] target.push_back(target_vt(element));` works.

Comment: I don't have a visual studio instance to hand, but could you work around this by having a `typedef` locally in the function for the `value_type`?

Comment: @J.N, may be you should post that as an answer?

Comment: @J.N & Nim: Thank you for the workaround - but this is not what i'm interested in. I just wanted to know whether it should compile or not.

Answer (score 1):

Your line is valid: http://ideone.com/qAF7r

Even the ancient g++ 4.3 compiles it. So it's probably a bug in your MS compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry don't have VS2010 available. Try moving the typedef outside of lambda. Works on g++.

```
#include <list> 
#include <vector> 
#include <algorithm> 

template <typename source_container_type, typename target_container_type> 
void copy_all(const source_container_type& source, target_container_type& target) 
 {
    typedef typename target_container_type::value_type TargetType; /// Code change here.

    std::for_each(source.begin(), source.end(), [&] (const typename source_container_type::value_type& element) 
    { 
         target.push_back(TargetType(element)); 
    }); 
} 

int main() 
{ 
    std::vector<int> a; 
    a.push_back(23); 
    a.push_back(24); 
    a.push_back(25); 

    std::list<int> b; 
    copy_all(a, b); 
}
```

Comment: Please note that i'm not interested in a workaround - i'm interested why the questionable code gives an error.

Answer (score 0):

I may be misunderstanding what you are trying to achieve but shouldn't the line in question simply be:

target.push_back(element);

Comment: This is needed if target_container_type::value_type has an explicit constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using C++0x/11, you can use:

```
target.push_back( (decltype(element))(element));
```

Comment: I just tried in ideone and did not compile. In fact, different compilers have different compliance issues. For eg. g++ does not compile if we use global std::begin and std::end.

Comment: what do you think `decltype` evaluates to, source element type or destination element type?

Comment: It evaluates to the type (say `T`). Then following expression means `T(e)` which is calling to constructor.

Comment: @Nim destination element type

Comment: @Jagannath: ideone uses an old g++ version that does not fully support C++11.

Comment: Well, yes. I made the mistake `element` is of source type, not destination type. And therefore, it wont call constructor of target type. I will probe more on it!

Comment: I know one thing for sure. VC10, doesn't inherit the namespace. So, even if function that is calling labmda has `std` included, you must use `std::` specification in lambda!

Comment: Yes. VC11 compiles the code (original as well as given on MS site).

Comment: This discussion doesn't answer the question - please see my edits in the question.